# Generate number of rows based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to generate a packing list using 2 worksheets. The 2nd Worksheet will get all the data and reference it into 1st Worksheet.

There is a items section in the 2nd Worksheet will take in a user input value of Integer as Totalpieces to generate a repeated rows of items records in the 1st Worksheet. Once the items section finishes the for loop, it should continue to loop through the outer for loop for the next section to reference to 1st Worksheet.

I have tried to do a for loop to copy all data from 2nd Worksheet to the 1st Worksheet. And a nested for loop for this items section but i have encountered macros looping indefinitely and crash the workbook.
Hope to seek your advice on how best to do this.

Below is the code for the 1st worksheet.

```
Dim No_Of_Shpt As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim source_row_number As Integer
Dim dest_row_number As Integer
Dim product As String
counter = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
source_row_number = 3
dest_row_number = 2
No_Of_Shpt = counter - 2

'Get User input here to repeat the items section with for loop
Dim p As Integer
Dim TotalPieces As Integer
TotalPieces = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("IT3").Value

For i = 1 To No_Of_Shpt

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & dest_row_number).Value = counter
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & dest_row_number).Value = "SHIP_FROM"

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & dest_row_number).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & source_row_number).Value

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & dest_row_number).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & source_row_number).Value

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & dest_row_number).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & source_row_number).Value

*****ITEMS SECTION*****
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & dest_row_number).Value = counter
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & dest_row_number).Value = "PACKAGING"

    For p = 1 To TotalPieces
        
'Select the cell area to start adding more rows 
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Activate

        If p = 1 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("BY3:CF3").Copy  'copy the first row item record and paste as first row record

            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
        Else
'copy the first row item record and paste as 2nd item record in the next row.
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("BY3:CF3").Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset((p - 1) * 8, 0).Activate
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
            
        End If
        
    Next p
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False


'*****Continue Outer for loop*******
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & dest_row_number).Value = counter
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & dest_row_number).Value = "EXTRA_SERVICE"

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & dest_row_number).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("CG" & source_row_number).Value


Else

End If

'add counter to read next row from source
source_row_number = source_row_number + 1

'this is to add counter to write to next row
dest_row_number = dest_row_number + 1

counter = counter + 1

Next i
```

Comment: Where and how did you initialize the variable `Totalpieces` in the code?

Comment: Updated the code to include the initialization. The user input will take place in 2nd worksheet. 
In summary: 
2nd Worksheet: Take input and reference data. 1st Worksheet: Generate list with for loop

Comment: Since the code is incomplete, I am not 100% sure what's going on.  One suggestion is to avoid using `.Activate()` or `.Select`, then `ActiveCell.xxxx` as the active cell might not be what you think. Just use `[your range].PasteSpecial`.  Also, the `Totalpieces` is supposed to be unchanged throughout both loops, right? (it is the case now)

Comment: The remaining codes are just to referencing data values between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Yes, totalpieces value should remain unchanged in both loops. Updated the code with comments for better understanding.

Comment: Which loop runs indefinitely? i or p?  Infinite loop normally results from 1) you modify the index variable within the loop, or 2) you set a very high limit that makes you think it runs indefinitely, and which cause the actions within the loop failed.  Try to set a breakpoint and step through the first few loops. Most likely you could figure out what went wrong.  Again, strongly recommend you to avoid using Activate() / Select().  (by moving the `.copy` statement out of the loop and use `For p = 0 To TotalPieces-1`, your inner loop only need 1 line of code)